# Using Write command to create new syntax - problem with unwanted spaces

Tags: syntax, spss

I am trying to run a command on a list of variables stored as values in a different file. To do that I am creating a new syntax based on the variable names, like this:

```
WRITE OUT="\Selection.sps" 
    /"VARIABLE ATTRIBUTE VARIABLES = Final_",Var1," ATTRIBUTE=selectVars('yes')." .
EXECUTE.
```

The Problem is between Final and Var1, I am getting 11 spaces. The file in which I want to use this macro has variable names as Final_Var1 (So in the new file, Final is added to each variable's Name). How can I remove the space so that the new variable can be referred to properly? Should I create a new file or `COMPUTE` and `CONCAT` commands?

Comment: Also, the variable Var1 has cases which are starting from 1 till 1000. Later on, these cases are converted to variables. I think something like TRIM must be used but this command works only with CONCAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `write` command is limited like that - you can't avoid the spaces or use `trim`. For commands like the one you're working on there is no way to build the command within the `write` command - you have to build the text in advance and then put it in the `write` command, so -

```
strimg mycmd(a100).
compute mycmd=concat("VARIABLE ATTRIBUTE VARIABLES = Final_", 
      ltrim(string(Var1,f4)), 
      " ATTRIBUTE=selectVars('yes').").
WRITE OUT="\Selection.sps" /mycmd .
exe.
```

Note that this is not the only way to work on variable lists - you can use Python code within the syntax to build your variable lists more efficiently.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I just added a few more lines to convert Var1 from Numeric to String.

Answer (score 1):

I  have found a temporary solution, in order to remove the spaces from the variables, I am creating a new variable using:

```
    *Add a variable to use in .sps file.
NUMERIC A(F4).
COMPUTE A = Var1. 
ALTER TYPE A (A25).
STRING CMD (A100).
COMPUTE CMD = CONCAT("VARIABLE ATTRIBUTE VARIABLES = Final_", LTRIM (A) , ATTRIBUTE=selectVars('yes').").   
EXECUTE.

WRITE OUT="File location\Selection.sps" /CMD.
EXECUTE.
```

and now a macro can be created using Selection.sps.

If a simpler way exists, please let me know!